# Solving Poisson Equation Proof in Lawrence C. Evans Theorem 1 page 23

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, integral-inequality

I am trying to understand a proof of a theorem in L.C. Evans related to Poisson Equation. However, there are some steps which I do not understand.

Here is the statement of the theorem:

**Theorem 1**. Let $u$ be a function defined as the following:
$$u(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\Phi(x-y)f(y)dy$$
given that $\Phi(x) = \Phi(|x|) = \begin{cases} -\frac{1}{2\pi}\log|x| & (n=2) \\ \frac{1}{n(n-2)\alpha(n)} \frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}} & (n \geq 3) \end{cases}$ with $\alpha(n)$ as the volume of a unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $f : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$.
Then (i) $u \in C^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and (ii) $-\Delta u = f$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

So that is the statement of the theorem. In proving this theorem, I have several things that I can't understand quite well.


First, is this statement:
Fix  $\varepsilon > 0$. Then
$\Delta u(x) = \int_{B(0,\varepsilon)}\Phi(y)\Delta_{x}f(x-y)dy + \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}-B(0,\varepsilon)}\Phi(y)\Delta_{x}f(x-y)dy =: I_{\varepsilon}+K_{\varepsilon}$ (eq.11)
Now
$|I_{\varepsilon}| \leq C ||D^{2}f||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\int_{B(0,\varepsilon)}\Phi(y)dy\leq \begin{cases} C\varepsilon^{2}|\log\varepsilon|& (n=2) \\ C\varepsilon& (n \geq 3)\end{cases}$ (eq.12)
An integration by parts yields
$$J_{\varepsilon}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}-B(0,\varepsilon)}\Phi(y)\Delta_{x}f(x-y)dy = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}-B(0,\varepsilon)}D\Phi(y)D_{y}f(x-y)dy+\int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)}\Phi(y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial \nu}(x-y)dS(y)$$ 
$$ J_{\varepsilon} =: K_{\varepsilon} + L_{\varepsilon}\quad \text{(eq.13)}$$
with $\nu$ denoting the inward pointing unit normal along $\partial B(0,\varepsilon)$. We readily check
$|L_{\varepsilon}|\leq ||Df||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)}|\Phi(y)|dS(y)\leq \begin{cases} C\varepsilon\log|\varepsilon| & (n=2) \\ C\varepsilon & (n \geq 3) \end{cases}$ (eq.14)

So, my question is, how do I get the inequality in (eq.12) and (eq.14)? Also I find it weird that in (eq.13) the book uses $\Delta_{y}$ instead of $\Delta_{x}$. Is there any explanation of why they can do it like that?

As for the last part, I also don't understand about this part:
$$K_{\varepsilon} = -\frac{1}{n\alpha(n)\varepsilon^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)}f(x-y)dS(y)$$
$$K_{\varepsilon}=-\,\,\mathrel{\int\!\!\!\!\!\!-}_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)}f(y)dS(y)\to-f(x)$$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$
Why can we argue that it converges to $f$ as $\varepsilon$ goes to zero?

Thank you very much and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a little bit since I've read Evans so I write this with caution, but if I remember correctly we use $\Delta_y$ because the dummy variable inside the integral is in y, and so it's important to make that difference to which variable you are taking the derivative of. This really only takes place because you are repeatedly integrating by parts with some of these integrals.

As for $K_\epsilon$, that second integral should be over $\partial B(x,\epsilon)$, and the reason for its limit is that (as you seem to have ommited), we assume $f \in C^2_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$(use this!), so you should be able to show for all $\eta>0$, that

$$\left|\frac{1}{n\alpha(n)\epsilon^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)} f(y)\,dS(y) - f(x)\right|<\eta$$

Comment: Thank you but I still can't show from your hint... Do I use integration by parts?
As for (eq.12), do you have any clue/hint to help me?

Comment: because of continuity, we may say for all $\delta>0$, $|f(y)-f(x)|<\delta$. So it amounts to computing

$$\frac{\delta}{n \alpha (n) \epsilon^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}dS$$.

Comment: As for Eq 12, the first is due to just bounding the derivative via the infinity(think max) norm, so that shouldn't be an issue. Afterwards, you need to directly compute that integral, 

$$\int_{B(0,\varepsilon)}\Phi(y)dy$$

Which is literally what the next part is saying, because we know $\Phi(y)$ is different for $n=2$.

Comment: Thanks! I finally figured out what you mean! Thank you very much

Comment: I have question: how can we get inequality (14)?

Comment: I had similar issues and I've just realized I can't understand the second inequality in (eq.12), either. I couldn't find an appropriate value for $C$ analytically, so I've plotted the left and the right hand side as functions of $\varepsilon$ and I can make sense of it. For instance, between 0 and $10^{-5}$ the RHS stays underneath the LHS even taking $C=10^5$. Indeed, $x$ the LHS seems to be concave and the RHS convex, so I can't see why such a $C$ must exist.

Comment: @DaveNine can you tell me why for $K_{\epsilon}$ we have taken limit over $\partial B(x,\epsilon)$?