# Questions about Solving Poisson's equation in Evan's PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

In this post[Solving Poisson Equation Proof in Lawrence C. Evans Theorem 1 page 23](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2476244/solving-poisson-equation-proof-in-lawrence-c-evans-theorem-1-page-23), someone has asked about the inequalities 12 and 14, which also confused me. I can understand the approximation of derivatives of $f$ (using norm), but I can't understand how to yield approximation of
$$
\int_{B\left( 0,\varepsilon \right)}^{}{|\Phi \left( y \right) |\mathrm{d}y}.
$$
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180851/evans-book-pde-estimate-question

Comment: @Flashhh Thanks:)